# both 4.15 and 5.4 kernels at the same time

Tags: release-hera, kernel

`find /boot/v*` gives me

```
/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-141-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-70-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-71-generic
```

and the kernel in use is

```
uname -r
5.4.0-71-generic
```

I am wondering, why I'm still getting updates for 4.15 branch too? Is it ok?
Also it's impossible to delete the kernel via `sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.15.0-141-generic` due to dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current state of things is:

```
arti@hp: find /boot/v*
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-71-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic
```

This is what I did in order to achieve the desired result:
uninstalled 4.15 kernel, however upon uninstall I've got 4.15 `unsigned` kernel, so I removed it too. In order to keep only 5+ version I removed the *linux-libc-dev* repository via

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-libc-dev
sudo apt-get purge linux-libc-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning be very careful , these instructions may break your boot sequence

maybe you have two boot partitions /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2 if you want boot the new kernels run again  grub-install and update-grub .

```
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```